# Java 8 - return List (keyset) opposed to List<Map.Entry<Integer, CheckBox>>

Tags: java, java-8, vaadin

I am trying to use java 8 to return me a list of key values(Integers) in which the value (Checkbox) is checked. The map I am trying to process is of the following form.

```
Map<Integer, CheckBox>
```

The aim is to return the key set for all values where the check box value is checked.

If I do the following

```
checkBoxes.entrySet().stream().filter(c -> c.getValue().getValue())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

then I get back a `List<Map.Entry<Integer, CheckBox>>` Is there anyway to do this all in one line without processing the Map.Entry values so I can just get a list of integers?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add a `map` call to extract the key from the Entry :

```
List<Integer> keys = checkBoxes.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(c -> c.getValue().getValue())
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you very much. Looks like I need to go away and learn this some more as I wasn't aware that could be done. Thank you